# applying autosave features with javafx

Tags: javafx

I am creating an application for project management which has various features including saving and opening the saved file. My application is running smoothly but i want to add another feature in the application which will allow it to save the data after some time.

Here is my code for the save  and save as functions.

```
 @FXML
private void handleSave() {
    File userstoryFile = mainApp.getUserStoryFilePath();
    if (userstoryFile != null) {
        mainApp.saveUserStoryDataToFile(userstoryFile);
    } else {
        handleSaveAs();
    }
}

/**
 * Opens a FileChooser to let the user select a file to save to.
 */
@FXML
private void handleSaveAs() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    // Set extension filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
            "XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    // Show save file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());

    if (file != null) {
        // Make sure it has the correct extension
        if (!file.getPath().endsWith(".xml")) {
            file = new File(file.getPath() + ".xml");
        }
        mainApp.saveUserStoryDataToFile(file);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add autosave feature here ( using timer function )? if yes, How?

[click here to get complete application code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8-9t3YdmveoN1FsajNZZ3FqRlU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be easy to implement using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

```
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> mainApp.saveUserStoryDataToFile(file), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

For saving the data with a delay of one minute between saves (no initial delay).

Note that using this approach you need to take care of a few things:

- Synchronize access to the data.
- Prevent concurrent access to the file.
- Making sure `shutdown` is called when (or before) the JavaFX platform exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it and let you know.